# What might be ruining my mob grinder on the craftgasm server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Ok so I have built a pretty typical mob grinder. (4 8x8 spawning pads with a "+" shaped water funneling system three vertical floors of that config water only at the bottom.)

So as I said pretty typical, and functioning, I built a replica in creative with ideal everything. The thing churns 'em out like you would expect.

My question, I built this thing in my factions territory on the craftgasm server. At almost the sky limit. (To cut out the "underground caverns" kryptonite) and spits out mobs at a painfully slow pace. Like slower than what I would expect based off of the vanilla minecraft creative tests. (Even giving it a time handicap, the thing isn't working)

The testing led me to think it was bats. I go up to check, no bats even. I have checked my distance from the spawner, that's not it.

Maybe the server is doing something? Maybe it is set up to prevent hostile mobs from spawning in your territory? Not sure. I put it to you, kind users of the Internet. What are your thoughts?

Comment: spawning locations are checked at chunk level so height doesn't matter at that point, also mobs might be spawning in caverns loaded by other players and not despawning there

Comment: Pretty sure that wouldn't be it. As my grinder is beyond 128 blocks from sea level. And there aren't really any other places around that could have caverns. So unless they are there in the cavern (player not mob)they would despawn.

Comment: Height actually decreases mob spawning.

Comment: Oh? How do you mean. I haven't really seen that.

Comment: Are you alone on the server? I am not familiar with those mods, but vanilla spawning algorithm does not try to spawn each player's allotment of mobs exactly around this player. I.e. if one player goes to sea or the sky, his portion of mobs are essentially dumped on other people. The game spawns mobs wherever it is easier.

Comment: Sorry, never mind that! Apparently altitude limiting spawns [was a bug in 1.4.5 and earlier](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Spawn) and has since been fixed.

Comment: Multiplayer servers can also be affected by lag.  If the server is overburdened and can't keep up with the tick updates, mob spawning rates will often be affected.  On a couple larger servers I've played on, it is not uncommon to run around outside during the night and not see a single mob even in pitch darkness.

Comment: While I am not alone on e server. I am reasonably sure that the "bubble" that mobs can spawn in, contains only me. It feels like the server lag might be part of it, as I have noticed the same thing mellamokb brings up. Walking around at night and never encountering mobs. I just hold out hope that it isn't that, as I can't do anything about that, lol.

Comment: Nether portals affect chunk loading behavior as well. If there is a nether portal that has been used in the last 60 sec it will cause a large area around the nether portal coords (not the overworld portal it is linked to) to remain loaded and spawn mobs.

Also of note: hoppers spanning chunk boundaries can expand that area as well, so watch for compounding issues with any attempt to micromanage chunk loading mechanics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I'm going just chalk this one up to lag. Between someone's suggestion on here, and low mob encounters in general on that server... Thanks to all that tryed to figure this one out with me.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not dark enough. Try closing off all entries to the spawners.

Comment: There are no spawners referenced in the question, they are using the normal mob spawning rules.

Comment: What chargingpun said. This is a grinder, not a spawner trap. Would that I could obtain spawners. That would be suweeeeeeet.

Answer (score 0):

The Minecraft entity limit is based on chunks, not quasi-chunks.  You need to light up practically every dark area on the ground AND in caves in the surrounding chunks to have it work like you're saying.